# Xfce application finder one Enter keystroke

Tags: xfce

How to make application finder in Xfce 4 to launch an application with one Enter stroke when one choice is left?

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible since the `Launch` button is not enabled until your choice is highlighted by clicking on it.

But there is a workaround that's pretty close to what you want: two quick taps of <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of one.

When there is only one choice left (or when your choice is at the top of the list), the first `Enter` will highlight your choice and the second will launch it.

Comment: I knew that, but thank you. This is sad, that they do not have such a simple improvement.